# The @ symbol and systemctl and vsftpd

Tags: vsftpd, systemd

I have a two part question.

> 1. What is the significance of the @ symbol in systemctl scripts?
> 2. How to start vsftpd in fedora 16, (which in some tutorials seems to contain an @ in it's name)? I have done everything the tutorials say,
>      and it still gives me an error.
>      http://blog.tuxforge.com/fedora-16-vsftpd/

What I've done

```
systemctl enable vsftpd@.service
```

What I see

```
Failed to issue method call: No such file or directory
```

(I have tried this with a absolute path as well, and after I checked there is no such file. The real file does not contain an @ sign, and is located under the /lib/systemd/system/ directory. I have also tried starting and enabling with and without the @ symbol, enabling works, but starting doesn't. **I realize the article is now obsolete, but I still cannot seem to start the service. When I try to connect it doesn't let me)**

**EDIT: I got the service to start somehow, but I would still like to know what the @ symbol means in some service names. Also I am still getting a login error number #500 cannot change directory [...], what does this mean?**

To start it I just typed

```
sudo systemctl enable vsftpd.service

sudo systemctl start vsftpd.service (the problem was I was using an absolute path for this I think)
```

Answer (score 97, accepted):

The `@` symbol is for special services, sockets, and other units where multiple instances can be run.

For instance, `getty@.service` is the service that provides text login terminals.  When you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, `getty@tty2.service` is started, creating virtual terminal #2.

Another service that uses this functionality is OpenVPN.  You can create a file `/etc/openvpn/work.conf`, configured to connect to the VPN at your workplace, and then `systemctl start openvpn@work.service` to connect to it.  Similarly, you could create `/etc/openvpn/home.conf`, then start `openvpn@home.service` if you had a VPN at home.  This prevents you from having to create a `.service` file for every VPN you connect to.

But don't take my word for it.  Try it out!  Let's create a simple service that outputs a message to syslog.  Create a file `/etc/systemd/system/echo@.service` with the following contents:

```
[Unit]
Description=Echo '%I'

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/echo %i
StandardOutput=syslog
```

Notice the `%i`?  systemd will populate that with whatever follows the `@` sign when the service is started.  So, try starting `echo@foo.service`:

```
systemctl start echo@foo.service
```

Then, check the [journal](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-journald.service.html):

```
 journalctl -n10
```

At the bottom, you'll see that systemd ran `/bin/echo foo`:

```
Feb 24 12:41:01 localhost echo[8412]: foo
```

Now, try `systemctl start echo@bar.service`.  This time, systemd will populate `%i` with `bar`, so you'll see:

```
Feb 24 12:42:51 localhost echo[8432]: bar
```

That's all there is to it!  Anything could potentially follow the `@` sign, as systemd just replaces `%i` in the service definition with it.  OpenVPN uses it for configuration, other services might use for something else, like a port number.

For more information, see [`man systemd.unit`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html).

Comment: are they started and stopped like normal services except for the inclusion of the @ symbol? For instance if I were to start the service for a second time, would I just do start again? How do u start multiple instances?

Comment: Yup, just change the text following the `@` sign to whatever's appropriate.  I added an example you can test out to see how it works.

Comment: @Patches: Where is a doc for "The @ symbol is for special services where multiple instances can be run."? I don't see it at https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html

Comment: It's described in [systemd.unit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Description).  It's also useful for [sockets](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.socket.html) and other types of units.  (Added to answer now, thanks.  :-)

Comment: What is the difference between %I and %i?